# Add additional fields to the postal address

Tags: nodes

How can I add additional fields to the *Address Field* module's *Postal address* field? I would like to add a field for the county.

The default fields for the United States are the following.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is a configuration in the field settings. If not in there I'd look at the module's config screen.

Comment: I looked, and was unable to find such a setting.

Comment: There is no setting for it even in Drupal 8.  The address field is actually a field type in itself. We need to update the schema by patching the module.